# Cannot create Data for Multi Part Form request

Tags: swift, multipartform-data, nsdata, urlsession

I am trying to send a `multipart/form-data` request via `URLSession` I have written a helper function to create the form body as `Data` for me, however my request keeps failing with a `500` response code.

I was trying to print out the string representation of my request to ensure the body is correct, however simply trying to decode it now is throwing an error as `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

This leads me to believe something is wrong with how my request is being encoded.

This is essentially my setup -

```swift
struct Media {
    let key: String
    let filename: String
    let data: Data
    let mimeType: String

    init?(withImage image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        self.filename = "avatar.jpg"

        guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7) else { return nil }
        self.data = data
    }
}

typealias Parameters = [String: String]

func createFormData(usingParams params: Parameters?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {
    let lineBreak = "\r\n"
    var body = Data()

    if let parameters = params {
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append(string:"--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append(string:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append(string:"\(value + lineBreak)")
        }
    }

    if let media = media {
        for photo in media {
            body.append(string:"--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append(string:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(photo.key)\"; filename=\"\(photo.filename)\"\(lineBreak)")
            body.append(string:"Content-Type: \(photo.mimeType + lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append(photo.data)
            body.append(string: lineBreak)
        }
    }

    body.append(string: "--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")

    return body
}

extension Data {
    mutating func append(string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Which I invoke something like this -

```swift
        let boundary = UUID().uuidString
        guard let profilePic = Media(withImage:image, forKey: "file") else { return }

        let data = createFormData(usingParams: nil, media: [profilePic], boundary: boundary)
```

I have tried to print my data using the following -

```
do {
    print(data)
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
    print(json)
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This throws the error mentioned earlier.

I have also tried

```swift
        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)

        print(string)
```

This however just returns nil.

I noticed if I remove `body.append(photo.data)` the data can print out now as JSON, however I am not sure why this matters

Comment: Are you setting the Content-Type header properly as "multipart/form-data; boundary=(YOUR BOUNDARY)"?

Comment: Yes. Also, Strangely the request goes through if I send a `POST` request, however if I send a `PUT` the body is `nil`